# Check/DeCheck all items in Check-list box vb.net

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, copy

A couple of questions about check list boxes:

1. How to check/decheck all the item in the list
2. How do you copy or delete all checked items in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can scan the CheckedItems and CheckedIndices properties, you cannot modify them at the same time.  Make a copy of the collection and process the copy instead.

Uncheck all checked items:

```
Dim CheckedIndices(CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1) As Integer
CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndices.CopyTo(CheckedIndices, 0)
For Each Index As Integer In CheckedIndices
    CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(Index, False)
Next
```

Delete all checked items:

```
Dim CheckedItems(CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1) As Object
CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.CopyTo(CheckedItems, 0)
For Each CheckedItem As Object In CheckedItems
    ' Alternateively, add code to copy CheckedItem here.
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Remove(CheckedItem)
Next
```

EDIT: Changed array declarations to (.Count - 1).  VB's declaration syntax in infuriating sometimes.

Comment: how would i just get the name of the item so i could use it in a filepath?

Comment: What objects did you add to the list box?  If each object is a String, you can safely replace the term "Object" with "String".  If it is a FileInfo object, replace "Object" with "FileInfo", then use the FileInfo's properties.